# How to read bytes line by line in Java using NIO or apache commons IO? Whichever is more efficent

Tags: java, nio, apache-commons-io

I have bunch of bytes written line by line into a file so that each line can have varying number of bytes and now I need to read them line by line I am wondering how to do that in an efficient way using NIO or apache commons IO? I am trying to see if there is a way an API can take care of allocation and deallocation of buffers since I dont know the length of bytes in each line. I can certainly read it as a String and do .getBytes().length() but that sounds a bit awkward.

Comment: "I can certainly read it as a String and do .getBytes().length() but that sounds a bit awkward" ... well, there's your solution, isn't it?

Comment: well I always assume someone is more knowledgable than me and may be able to come up with creative ways. What are your thoughts on apache commons.io interface in regards to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the file really consists of lines, you can read millions of lines a second with `BufferedReader.readLine().` You don't need anything else. In any case NIO doesn't support reading lines in any way shape or form.

Comment: BufferedReader.readLine() will still return a string. I am trying to see if there is any way to read bytes line by line!

Comment: And get what back? A byte array? Nothing like that in the JDK, but you can convert any `String` into a byte array yourself.